# Почему не работает фильтр WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

помогите пожалуйста с такой проблемой.

На странице есть фильтр для поиска домов, по микрорайону(это рубрики), цене и площади. После отправки запроса по AJAX, вывожу дома, но сейчас это не работает, выбираю нужную категорию, а в результате всё равно получаю все зарегистрированные дома, а не конкретно выбранного микрорайона, где у меня ошибка?

Страница с архивом домов

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
<?php
    if( $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'category', 'orderby' => 'name' ) ) ) : 

        echo '<select name="categoryfilter"><option value="">Select category...</option>';
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
            echo '<option value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
        endforeach;
        echo '</select>';
    endif;
?>
<input type="text" name="price_min" placeholder="Min price" />
<input type="text" name="price_max" placeholder="Max price" />
<button>Apply filter</button>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">
```

JS файл

```
$('#filter').submit(function(){
    var filter = $('#filter');
    $.ajax({
        url:filter.attr('action'),
        data:filter.serialize(), // form data
        type:filter.attr('method'), // POST
        beforeSend:function(xhr){
            filter.find('button').text('Processing...'); // changing the button label
        },
        success:function(data){
            filter.find('button').text('Apply filter'); // changing the button label back
            $('#response').html(data); // insert data
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

functions.php

```
function new_filter_function(){
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'date'
);

// categories
if( isset( $_POST['categoryfilter'] ) )
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter']
        )
    );

if( isset( $_POST['price_min'] ) && $_POST['price_min'] || isset( $_POST['price_max'] ) && $_POST['price_max'] )
    $args['meta_query'] = array( 'relation'=>'AND' );

if( isset( $_POST['price_min'] ) && $_POST['price_min'] && isset( $_POST['price_max'] ) && $_POST['price_max'] ) {
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key' => '_price',
        'value' => array( $_POST['price_min'], $_POST['price_max'] ),
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'between'
    );
} else {

    if( isset( $_POST['price_min'] ) && $_POST['price_min'] )
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => '_price',
            'value' => $_POST['price_min'],
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '>'
        );

    if( isset( $_POST['price_max'] ) && $_POST['price_max'] )
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => '_price',
            'value' => $_POST['price_max'],
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '<'
        );
}


$query = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type'   => 'houses',
] );

if( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="slider__item">
            <div class="slider__img">
                <a class="slider__link" href="#"></a>
                <img src="img/slider1.png" alt="дом">
            </div>
            <div class="slider__info">
                <div class="info-name">
                    <span class="info-micro">новые сады</span>
                    <div class="info-discription">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info-icons">
                        <div class="info-icons-item beds">
                            <img src="img/bed.png" alt="спальни">
                            <span>2</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info-icons-item bathrooms">
                            <img src="img/shower.png" alt="ванные">
                            <span>2</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="info-price">
                    <div class="area">
                        45<span class="postfix">м<sup>2</sup></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="main-price">
                        3 500 000<span class="postfix">₽</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="metr-price">
                        45 000<span class="postfix">₽ / м<sup>2</sup></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
else :
    echo 'No posts found';
endif;

die();
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот тут ошибка

```
$query = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type'   => 'houses',
] );
```

нужно заменить на

```
$args['post_type'] = 'houses';

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

т.е. Вы сформировали параметры для WP_Query, но используете только параметр post_type

Comment: Большое спасибо! @Valerii Vasiliev

Comment: скажите пожалуйста, а если я дому задаю цену через ACF, как мне привязать её к этому скрипту?

Comment: @DmitriyMedvedkin точно также как Вы привязали другие POST параметры

Comment: я в WP пока нубище, я имею ввиду вместо какого значения мне надо подставить цену дома the_field('cost-house');  в коде который я представил(он не мой)

Comment: @DmitriyMedvedkin в Вашем коде есть все ответы

Comment: 'key' => the_field('cost-house');',
пробовал так, но не работает

Comment: @DmitriyMedvedkin создайте отдельный вопрос по wp_query и acf